# Using swift function with return value and completion block in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've set up my project to be able to use swift files in Obj-c classes but for some reason I cant call functions that have return types and completion blocks.

```
@objc class AgentManager : NSObject {
static let instance = AgentManager()

// the sharedInstance class method can be reached from ObjC.
class func sharedInstance() -> AgentManager {
    return AgentManager.instance
}

func fetchAgentInfo(agentID: String, completion:(result: Agent) ->    Void) { //...networking code }
```

in the objective-c file:

```
AgentManager *manager = [AgentManager sharedInstance];
[manager fetchAgentInfo:@"string" completion:^(Agent *response) {
    //No visible @interface for 'AgentManger' declares the
    //selector fetchAgentInfo:completion:
}];
```

************Solution*************:

I was trying to return an Agent struct. You cant use Swift structs in Objc. I just converted it to a class.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in completion's block signature. Please try this code:

```
[self.manager fetchAgentInfo:@"string" completion:^(AgentManager * _Nonnull result) {

}];
```

Also you have two classes AgentManager and Agent, I assumed that these two are the same class and it was just a typo.

Comment: Im actually returning an Agent struct

Comment: That explains whats is wrong, sad to say you can't use swift structs in objective-c. You can try to use class instead.